# How do you configure secure DNS (aka "private DNS") with cloudflare?

Tags: security, dns, private-dns

note: there are a lot of DNS questions on android.stackexchange.com I'm creating this question because all the other DNS questions were for different scenarios and I wanted to keep this up to date over the years.

I do not want my DNS queries to be unencrypted whenever I am doing any internet activity (either through cellular mobile internet or through wifi with home internet).

#### How do you configure secure DNS (aka "private DNS") with cloudflare?

Answer (score 1):

#### In a nutshell or `tldr` summary:

For android 9 or later:

- open settings
- search for `dns`
- touch the `Private DNS`
  ** a dialog box opens with three options**
- select the last option called `Priavte DNS provider hostname`
- fill in `one.one.one.one`
- test by going to address `https://1.1.1.1/help`

**warning: any wifi network that uses a `Captive Portal` will stop all your internet. when you are on a wifi network that uses `Captive Portal`, you have to go back to `settings/Private DNS` and set it to `off` then follow the `Captive Portal` instructions then go back to `settings/Private DNS` back on.**

---

#### for the full story keep reading here:

##### follow the docs:

Cloudflare has some really good documentation that is short and understandable (Google also has good documentation but I had trouble following their documentation).

- The Cloudflare help starts at: `https://1.1.1.1/help`
- click at the bottom for `FAQ` then look for the developer docs link which is: `https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/` (this has docs for pretty much any computer (android, windows, mac, linux, etc, etc))
- click on `android`. follow the directions given or use my summary directions.

##### follow the summary of the docs:

Option 1: For android 9 or later:

- open settings
- search for `dns`
- touch the `Private DNS`
  ** a dialog box opens with three options**
- select the last option called `Priavte DNS provider hostname`
- fill in `one.one.one.one`
- test by going to address `https://1.1.1.1/help`

Option 2: For android 8 or earlier (FYI i have not personally these instructions because I do not have an older android phone):

- settings --> wifi --> modify network --> show advanced options
- using your on screen keyboard copy the current text to somewhere (in case something goes wrong)
- type in or copy and paste the following

```
1.1.1.1
1.0.0.1
2606:4700:4700::1111
2606:4700:4700::1001
```

- save
- test by going to address `https://1.1.1.1/help`

Option 3: Lastly you can download their app but I have not tried it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone&hl=en_US&gl=US

##### **warning: any wifi network that uses a `Captive Portal` will stop all your internet. when you are on a wifi network that uses `Captive Portal`, you have to go back to `settings/Private DNS` and set it to `off` then follow the `Captive Portal` instructions then go back to `settings/Private DNS` back on.**

---

#### Addendum

##### important note: some internet providers block secure DNS

- i used to use `dns.google` in my android phone but it stopped working in 2022-01 for unknown reasons

  - same behavior for when you connect to a wifi network that uses captive portal and your android phone says it can not connect to the internet because the wifi network is blocking your internet
- i did a google search and found others had similar issues (private DNS not working on their cellular internet)
- for a brief like week i was able to use the alternative Cloudflare hostname `1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com` but that also stopped working
- i wrote this because it took me so long to get this working so i wanted to document it all and make it easier for others

##### if you do not like Cloudflare there are other providers of Secure DNS

- google has some docs here: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using
- quad9 is another (i've not used quad9 so i can not say anything about them)